# Speeding up the dex process with jar files, is it possible?

Tags: android, scala

I have an "older" machine which is more than adequate for developing my first Android marketplace application BUT only with Java!

I recently tried *Kawa* and *Scala* (I switch to functional programming about six years ago with LISP/Scheme and I've absorbed Erlang and Haskell since then) and I must say that I really love Scalas conciseness and Kawa is *still* fantastic (used it a long time ago for a project).

However... the build time when "dexing" on my machine is into the minutes(!) when the 'dx' program works on the kawa.jar file.

Does anybody know if it is possible to "cache" or "pre-build" a Jar file so that the desxing process only does what has changed. It is just a little irritating and sad to see it dexing the jar files I've used even though they are the same as last time.

I could buy a faster new machine but I don't have the spare dosh right now so I want to know what optimisations I could make...
:(
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This article might help - [Custom Class Loading in Dalvik](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html). You would have to use multiple pre-compiled dex files and perform some of the class loading yourself as required.

Comment: That's not a small job.  It's also tough to do things like write services in Scala - there's no hook to tell Android to use your new classloader to load the service.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could preinstall kawa.jar on your (rooted) android device, see here: http://zegoggl.es/2011/07/how-to-preinstall-scala-on-your-android-phone.html